# C array of structs segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I am trying to make a dynamic array of structs, and I can successfully add one struct to it. But any more structs I add cause a segmentation fault. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PEOPLE_BLOCK 4

struct Person {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int add_person(struct Person **people, size_t *people_size, size_t *population, struct Person p) {

    if ((sizeof(struct Person) * *population) > *people_size) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((sizeof(struct Person) * (*population + 1)) >= *people_size) {
        *people_size = *people_size + sizeof(struct Person) * PEOPLE_BLOCK;
        *people = realloc(*people, *people_size);
        if (!*people) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    *people[*population] = p;
    ++*population;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    size_t population;
    size_t people_size;
    struct Person *people, timn, batman;

    population = 0;
    people_size = sizeof(struct Person) * PEOPLE_BLOCK;
    people = malloc(people_size);

    timn.first_name = "Timn";
    timn.last_name = "Timothy";
    timn.age = 38;
    add_person(&people, &people_size, &population, timn);

    printf("Person 0's first name: %s\n", people[0].first_name);

    batman.first_name = "Bat";
    batman.last_name = "Man";
    batman.age = 42;
    add_person(&people, &people_size, &population, batman);

    printf("Person 1's first name: %s\n", people[1].first_name);

    free(people);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on why this is happening, thanks!

Comment: What is your purpose for the leading `if` block in `add_person` ? And similarly, the point of the return value of the same function if you never check it on the caller side?

Comment: Now that I notice that leading if, that's from something I changed and forgot to take out. And eventually I'd check the return value once I got it to work

Comment: You may not want to directly `*people = realloc(*people, *people_size);`. What if `realloc` fails? `realloc` returns `NULL` and you lose your pointer to all data. Better to create a `tmp` pointer and `tmp = realloc(*people, *people_size);`, then `if (tmp) *people = tmp;`.

Comment: @Addison If the question was answered mark at least one answer as the one so this post is technically closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem resides with this line :

```
*people[*population] = p;
```

Change it to:

```
(*people)[*population] = p;
```

**Why are the parenthesis requried?**

The compiler has [rules of *operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). When applying them, it sees your code as this:

```
*(people[*population]) = p;
```

which is not what you intended. Given a pointer-to-pointer `Type **pp`,

```
*pp[n] = value;
```

means "take the `n`'th pointer starting at `pp`, and assign `value` at the location dereferenced from the address that pointer holds. In other words, it means essentially this:

```
Type *p = pp[n];
*p = value;
```

What you *really* want is something that does *this*:

```
Type *p = *pp;
p[n] = value;
```

and that is what `(*pp)[n]`, distinguishing the dereference of the pointer to pointer, gives you. Without that, you're using an invalid pointer, leading to your fault.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this answer will help, but anyway.
I don't understand your code, what you are trying to do.

You directly use the number of elements, a pointer to the first person, and the maximum number of elements. You'll probably have a lot of problems passing that all around.

You're storing literal strings directly in your structs, which means that in a real case (using no literals) that would result in memory leaks.

Here is my take. I've made PEOPLE_BLOCK smaller for testing reasons.
Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PEOPLE_BLOCK 2

typedef struct _Person {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    unsigned int age;
} Person;

typedef struct _VectorPeople {
    Person * people;
    size_t num;
    size_t max;
} VectorPeople;

void init(VectorPeople *v)
{
    v->max = PEOPLE_BLOCK;
    v->num = 0;
    v->people = (Person *) malloc( sizeof(Person) * v->max );
}

void clear(VectorPeople *v)
{
    // Clear persons
    Person * it = v->people;
    while( ( it - v->people ) < v->num ) {
        free( it->first_name );
        free( it->last_name );

        ++it;
    }

    // Clear vector
    v->max = v->num = 0;
    free( v->people );
    v->people = NULL;
}

void add(VectorPeople *v, Person *p)
{
    // Reserve
    if ( v->num >= v->max ) {
        v->max += PEOPLE_BLOCK;

        // Realloc
        v->people = realloc( v->people, v->max * sizeof(Person) );
        if ( v->people == NULL ) {
            exit( -1 );
        }
    }

    // Copy strings
    p->first_name = strdup( p->first_name );
    p->last_name = strdup( p->last_name );

    // Insert
    v->people[ ( v->num )++ ] = *p;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    VectorPeople vp;
    Person timn;
    Person batman;
    Person bond;
    Person superman;

    init( &vp );

    timn.first_name = "Timn";
    timn.last_name = "Timothy";
    timn.age = 38;
    add( &vp, &timn );

    batman.first_name = "Batn";
    batman.last_name = "Man";
    batman.age = 42;
    add( &vp, &batman );

    bond.first_name = "James";
    bond.last_name = "Bond";
    bond.age = 45;
    add( &vp, &bond );

    superman.first_name = "Super";
    superman.last_name = "Man";
    superman.age = 45;
    add( &vp, &superman );

    int i = 0;
    for(; i < vp.num; ++i ) {
        printf( "Person: %s, %s.\n", vp.people[ i ].last_name, vp.people[ i ].first_name );
    }
    clear( &vp );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna have to try this approach

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of errors in your code. One thing to keep in mind, when you dynamically allocate memory, **you** are responsible for keeping track of it and freeing it when you no longer need it (otherwise, you will leak memory like a sieve).

In your code, you attempt to create an array of structs holding pointer to an array of characters. The `char *` pointers are NOT allocated and cannot simply be assigned in the manner you attempt. `strdup` can help, but you have just allocated memory, so `free` it when you are done with it.

Attempting to allocate an array of structs with varying (unknown) lengths of `first_name` and `last_name` requires that you keep track of every allocation. In some sense, you are better off declaring `people` as `pointer to pointer to Person` This allows iteration over your `people` without having to store the population somewhere allowing you to iterate until the first `NULL` pointer is encountered.

Likewise, creating a `typedef` to your struct can greatly cut down on the number of times you write `sizeof (struct Person)`. It keeps the code clean and helps you think though the pointer haze.

Here is an example using a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct of what I think you intended to do. It is followed below by an implementation using only a pointer to struct. Evaluate both and decide which implementation you prefer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPOP 128

typedef struct {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    unsigned char age;
} Person;

Person *add_person (Person ***ppl, Person p, size_t *pop, size_t *max);
Person **realloc_person (Person **ppl, size_t *n);
void free_person (Person *p);
void free_person_names (Person *p);

int main (void) {

    size_t population = 0;
    size_t maxp = MAXPOP;
    size_t i = 0;
    Person timn, batman;
    Person **people = calloc (MAXPOP, sizeof *people);

    if (!people) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    timn.first_name = strdup ("Timn");
    timn.last_name = strdup ("Timothy");
    timn.age = 38;
    add_person (&people, timn, &population, &maxp);
    free_person_names (&timn);

    printf("\nPerson 0\n first name: %s\n last name : %s\n age : %hhu\n",
            people[0]->first_name, people[0]->last_name, people[0]->age);

    batman.first_name = strdup ("Bat");
    batman.last_name = strdup ("Man");
    batman.age = 42;
    add_person (&people, batman, &population, &maxp);
    free_person_names (&batman);

    printf("\nPerson 1\n first name: %s\n last name : %s\n age : %hhu\n",
            people[1]->first_name, people[1]->last_name, people[1]->age);

    for (i = 0; i < population; i++)
        free_person (people[i]);
    free (people);

    return 0;
}

/* add a person to an array of pointers to Person */
Person *add_person (Person ***ppl, Person p, size_t *pop, size_t *max)
{
    if (*pop == *max)
        *ppl = realloc_person (*ppl, max);

    if (!((*ppl)[*pop] = malloc (sizeof ***ppl)))
        return NULL;

    size_t i = (*pop)++;
    (*ppl)[i]-> first_name = strdup (p.first_name);
    (*ppl)[i]-> last_name = strdup (p.last_name);
    (*ppl)[i]-> age = p.age;

    return (*ppl)[i];
}

/* realloc an array of pointers to Person setting memory to 0. */
Person **realloc_person (Person **ppl, size_t *n)
{
    Person **tmp = realloc (ppl, 2 * *n * sizeof *ppl);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ppl = tmp;
    memset (ppl + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *ppl); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return ppl;
}

/* free memory for a Person */
void free_person (Person *p)
{
    if (!p) return;
    if (p->first_name) free (p->first_name);
    if (p->last_name) free (p->last_name);
    free (p);
}

/* free only names of Person (for temp structs) */
void free_person_names (Person *p)
{
    if (!p) return;
    if (p->first_name) free (p->first_name);
    if (p->last_name) free (p->last_name);
}
```

**Note:** updated to correct `ppl` start address on reallocation.

---

### Using only Array of Person

While not inherently different than using a pointer to pointer to `Person` using a simple pointer to `Person` eliminates the ability to iterate over your array until a `NULL` or (empty) pointer is encountered. The following is an implementation of the same code using only an array of `Person`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPOP 128

typedef struct {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    unsigned char age;
} Person;

Person *add_person (Person **ppl, Person p, size_t *pop, size_t *max);
Person *realloc_person (Person *ppl, size_t *n);
void free_person_names (Person p);

int main (void) {

    size_t population = 0;
    size_t maxp = MAXPOP;
    size_t i = 0;
    Person timn, batman;
    Person *people = calloc (MAXPOP, sizeof *people);

    if (!people) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    timn.first_name = strdup ("Timn");
    timn.last_name = strdup ("Timothy");
    timn.age = 38;
    add_person (&people, timn, &population, &maxp);
    free_person_names (timn);

    printf("\nPerson 0\n first name: %s\n last name : %s\n age : %hhu\n", 
            people[0].first_name, people[0].last_name, people[0].age);

    batman.first_name = strdup ("Bat");
    batman.last_name = strdup ("Man");
    batman.age = 42;
    add_person (&people, batman, &population, &maxp);
    free_person_names (batman);

    printf("\nPerson 1\n first name: %s\n last name : %s\n age : %hhu\n", 
            people[1].first_name, people[1].last_name, people[1].age);

    for (i = 0; i < population; i++)
        free_person_names (people[i]);
    free (people);

    return 0;
}

/* add a person to an array of pointers to Person */
Person *add_person (Person **ppl, Person p, size_t *pop, size_t *max)
{
    if (*pop == *max)
        *ppl = realloc_person (*ppl, max);

    size_t i = (*pop)++;
    (*ppl)[i].first_name = strdup (p.first_name);
    (*ppl)[i].last_name = strdup (p.last_name);
    (*ppl)[i].age = p.age;

    return ppl[i];
}

/* realloc an array Person setting memory to 0. */
Person *realloc_person (Person *ppl, size_t *n)
{
    Person *tmp = realloc (ppl, 2 * *n * sizeof *ppl);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: struct reallocation failure.\n");
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ppl = tmp;
    memset (ppl + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *ppl); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return ppl;
}

/* free only names of Person (for temp structs) */
void free_person_names (Person p)
{
    if (p.first_name) free (p.first_name);
    if (p.last_name) free (p.last_name);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_add_person

Person 0
 first name: Timn
 last name : Timothy
 age : 38

Person 1
 first name: Bat
 last name : Man
 age : 42
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the last argument of add_person() to be specific, the argument '(struct Person) p'. When 'timn' and 'batman' are passed into the add_person() function, they are passed as a **copy** of the original structure. In the add_person() structure, that data is actually *on the stack* and is volatile outside the scope of the function. Try changing the last argument to a pointer.

Comment: What? It's a local variable yes but a *copy* is stored with `(*people)[*population] = p;` and that copy is not volatile. It is stored (As a valid variable). Like passing an int parameter to a function. If you store a copy in an array, it's not 'volatile'

Comment: My bad, but I was focusing more on the issue of copying a structure directly onto the stack prior to calling the function, which I try to avoid as I see it as bad programming practice, I did not look closely at how the stack is copied **again** into the allocated memory. The code is a bit over-complicated in how it was written.

Comment: You have a point. But i'm guessing that correct stack management and optimizations are probably not his primary concern. :-) And it definitely was written in an... interesting way. Those ifs are killing me.